# Finding Sum of the multiples of numbers 3 and 5 within a given range

Tags: c#

I attempted to project Euler #1 on hacker rank but I only got 60 points since the test case 2 and 3 are saying that my answer is wrong I cannot find my mistake.☹️

I've spend almost an hour thinking of a good formula; eventually, I got the following formula but it is outputting  wrong answer ☹️

the formula : d(n^2 + n) / 2

the code in c#:

```
using System;
class Solution {

    static void Main(String[] args) {
        int t = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] inputs = new int[t];
        for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
            inputs[a0] =Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()) -1;
        }
        foreach (int item in inputs)
        {
            int n = item /3;
            long s3 = 3*(n*n +n) /2;
            n = item / 5;
            long s5 = 5*(n*n +n) /2;
            n = item / 15;
            long s15 = 15*(n*n +n) /2;
            
            Console.WriteLine(s3 + s5 - s15);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: if (n > 29308) throw new Exception("Can't compute, overflow inevitable");

Comment: @Prageeth, dont forget to close your question by upvoting/validating the answer you prefer, this is how SO works..thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming  from the rounding...of your operation..and gives error for some datas  < 15

**solution tested and validated on hackerrank**:

```
static void Main(String[] args) {
    int t = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
        int item = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()) - 1;
         long s3  = item /3;
         long s5 = item / 5;
         long s15 = item / 15;
            s3 = sumN(s3) * 3;
            s5 = sumN(s5) * 5;
            s15 = sumN(s15) * 15;
        Console.WriteLine($"{s3 + s5 - s15}");
    }
}
static long sumN(long n) => (n * (n + 1)) / 2;
```

---

result

```
2 -> 0
4 -> 3
6 -> 8
10 -> 23
14 -> 45
16 -> 60
100 -> 2318
```

Answer (score 0):

The Euler problem asks for the sum of all numbers *less than* `n` but the summation formula you're using calculates the sum of all multiples up to *and including* `n`. i.e. `5*(n*n +n) /2` yields `15` for `n=10` but `5` for `n=9`.

Comment: No, because the OP reads the numbers with `Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()) -1`. Note the `- 1`?

Comment: You're right. I missed that when I dumped the code. I dropped the reads and just passed args. whoops

Answer (score 0):

I think your formula is correct.

The question is what you have to enter exactly. E.g. if you want the sum for the numbers below 10, then do you have to enter 9 or 10? I.e., is the input the inclusive or exclusive upper bound?

My advice is to explicitly ask for inclusive or exclusive upper bounds. In the following example I also created a local function for the sum.

```cs
Console.Write("Number of test cases: ");
int numberOfTestCases = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

int[] inputs = new int[numberOfTestCases];
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTestCases; i++) {
    Console.Write($"Inclusive upper bound #{i + 1}: ");
    inputs[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
foreach (int range in inputs) {
    long s3 = SumOfMultiples(range, 3);
    long s5 = SumOfMultiples(range, 5);
    long s15 = SumOfMultiples(range, 15);

    Console.WriteLine($"Range = {range}, Sum = {s3 + s5 - s15}");
}

static long SumOfMultiples(int range, int number)
{
    int n = range / number;
    return number * (n * n + n) / 2;
}
```

Example input/output:

```
Number of test cases: 2
Inclusive upper bound #1: 10
Inclusive upper bound #2: 20
Range = 10, Sum = 33
Range = 20, Sum = 98
```

It would also be legitimate to subtract 1 from the input and the ask for `Exclusive upper bound #n`. That way there is no confusion.